# Jquery Dynamic element not being recognized

Tags: jquery, json, dynamic, element

I seem to be stuck on an issue related to dynamic element creation. Elements added to DOM are not being recognized by jquery ".children" method. I want to hide my data before they are prepended, push into array and then animate them.

I have looked at .on() method, but I'm not certain how to bind the dynamic elements to make them recognizable. Any suggestions? Thanks!

**UPDATE FULL CODE:**

```
$(function() {
   var children = [];
   initInstagram();

   $("#main").children().each(function() {
     console.log(this);
     children.push(this);
   });

animateElements(children);

});

function animateElements(children) {
 if (children.length > 0) {
   var currentChild = children.shift();
   $(currentChild).fadeIn("slow", function() {
     animateElements(children);
   });
 }
}

function initInstagram() {
  $.getJSON('../includes/instagram.php',
  function(feeds) {
    var feedHTML = '';
    var displayCounter = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) {
      var imgURL = feeds[i].img;
      var caption = feeds[i].caption;         

      feedHTML = '<article class="box">';
      feedHTML += '<img src="'+imgURL+'" alt="'+caption+'" title="'+caption+'" >';
      feedHTML += '<div class="overlay"><h4>'+caption+'</h4></div>';
      feedHTML += '</article>';
      $(feedHTML).prependTo('#main').hide();              
    }        
 });
}
```

Comment: In this case once new items are added to the container you need to update the array separately. Where is the array `children` used?

Comment: Array children is used within $(function() { ... });

Comment: can you share the complete code

Comment: Sure. Main post has been updated with full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are using ajax to load the child elements your code will get executed asynchronously, you need to use a callback mechanism to solve this as given below

```
$(function() {
    initInstagram(function(feeds, children){
        $(children).hide()
        animateElements(children);
    });
});

function animateElements(children) {
    if (children.length > 0) {
        var currentChild = children.shift();
        $(currentChild).fadeIn("slow", function() {
            animateElements(children);
        });
    }
}

function initInstagram(callback) {
    $.getJSON('../includes/instagram.php', function(feeds) {
        var children = [];
        var feedHTML = '';
        var displayCounter = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) {
            var imgURL = feeds[i].img;
            var caption = feeds[i].caption;         

            feedHTML = '<article class="box">';
            feedHTML += '<img src="'+imgURL+'" alt="'+caption+'" title="'+caption+'" >';
            feedHTML += '<div class="overlay"><h4>'+caption+'</h4></div>';
            feedHTML += '</article>';
            var el = $(feedHTML).prependTo('#main');               
            children.push(el.get(0))           
        }     
        callback(feeds, children);
    });
}
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1lXMKhvjRppzvOys6x0?p=preview)

Comment: I don't believe this works accurately. Array is not being populated with the dynamic element.

Comment: also, I have updated my original post with full code. Basically I want to hide my data before they are prepended, push into array and then animate them.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this by using the DOMNodeInserted event:

```
var children = [];
$("#main").on('DOMNodeInserted', 'article', function() {
  console.log(this);
  children.push(this);
});

// get instagram data
$.getJSON('../includes/instagram.php',
  function(feeds) {
    var feedHTML = '';
    var displayCounter = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) {
      var imgURL = feeds[i].img;
      var caption = feeds[i].caption;         

  feedHTML = '<article class="box">';
  feedHTML += '<img src="'+imgURL+'" alt="'+caption+'" title="'+caption+'" >';
  feedHTML += '<div class="overlay"><h4>'+caption+'</h4></div>';
  feedHTML += '</article>';
  $(feedHTML).prependTo('#main');               
}});
```

OR because that event isn't well supported, create a custom event to trigger after insertion.

```
var children = [];
$("#main").on('customEvent', 'article', function() {
  console.log(this);
  children.push(this);
});

// get instagram data
$.getJSON('../includes/instagram.php',
  function(feeds) {
    var feedHTML = '';
    var displayCounter = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < feeds.length; i++) {
      var imgURL = feeds[i].img;
      var caption = feeds[i].caption;         

  feedHTML = '<article class="box">';
  feedHTML += '<img src="'+imgURL+'" alt="'+caption+'" title="'+caption+'" >';
  feedHTML += '<div class="overlay"><h4>'+caption+'</h4></div>';
  feedHTML += '</article>';
  $(feedHTML).prependTo('#main').trigger('customEvent');               
}});
```

Comment: CustomEvent such as? Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: custom events are simply events that you can define with any name. You can also pass params with them. See the jQuery docs for the trigger() method - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Would you mind taking a gander at my updated original code? Thanks again!

Comment: The second example I posted will work as is (with the event named "customEvent"). Not sure if you're trying to call the animateElements() method after the event is triggered, but if so, you'll need to put a call to it inside the vent handler.

Comment: Definitely after the event is triggered.

Comment: Then in the event handler, after `children.push(this);` add `animateElements(children);`